# STM32 timer period not accurate

Tags: timer, stm32

I've configured a timer to have a frequency of 1MHz, and I have an isr set up that runs every few microseconds. The problem is, the period that I measure on my logic analyzer is always off by 1us. If I set the timer frequency to be 1kHz, then the period is always off by 1ms. Is there a reason why this happens, or am I doing something wrong?

This is my current timer configuration, the actual period is 11us:

```
uint16_t PrescalerValue = (uint16_t) ((SystemCoreClock / 2) / 1000000) - 1;
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef  TIM_TimeBaseStructure;

/* Time base configuration */
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 10;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = PrescalerValue;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM7, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

/* TIM7 enable counter */
TIM_Cmd(TIM7, ENABLE);
```

I'm using TIM7 on an STM32F205xx with Keil.

Answer (score 1):

Timer period also calculated as Timer_Ticks-1, so line

```
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 10;
```

should be

```
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 9;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a reason why I have to subtract 1 from the period?